# Image is not coming up properly

Tags: python, django, web, backend

I'm working on a little e-commerce site. when I post a product from my site, the image(picture) doesn't show but when I post from the admin panel, the image shows so I don't why. I need help on this please. This is the code.
The code below is from the model.py

```
class OrderedItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The code below is from the views.py

```
def additem(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        stock_name = request.POST['stock_name']
        stock_price = request.POST['stock_price']
        stock_image = request.POST['stock_image']

        new_item = Stock(stock_name=stock_name, stock_price=stock_price, stock_image=stock_image)
        new_item.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'post.html')
```

the code below is from the html page

```
<form action="{% url 'additem' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="stock_name" id="" placeholder="stock_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="stock_price" id="" placeholder="stock_price">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="stock_image">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Additem" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you miss only image in POST request ?

Comment: yes, other information comes up except the image. When i post from the admin side, it works properly. But when i post from the the form i created, i experience that issue.

Comment: It need use request.FILES.get("name") to get the File and image field data

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: yeah its solved thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You need to add enctype='multipart/form-data' in the form otherwise no file will be accepted.

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

To get the images inputted in your html file

```
stock_image = request.FILES['stock_image']
```